# Executing tests in order in Playwright

Tags: typescript, unit-testing, playwright, playwright-typescript

So I've been working with Playwright on a project I'm on for work, and have seen the [docs](https://playwright.dev/docs/test-parallel#control-test-order) on it, but after doing it as they said, some of my tests are flaky and will fail using the same functions as other tests that will pass. The tests that pass and fail change every time, and I'm not sure if I just have it setup the wrong way, or what.

The best I can do for an example is this;

```js
import {test, expect} from '@playwright/test';
import {CustomPage} from '@classes';

let page: CustomPage;

test.describe('primaryTest', async () => {
   test.beforeAll(async ({browser}) => {
      page = new CustomPage(await browser.newPage());
   });

   test.beforeEach(async () => {
      await page.goTo("testUrl");
   });

   test.afterEach(async () => {
      await page.close();
   });

   test('example test', async () => {
      //Do tests things
      await page.commonFunc(); //Passes here
   });
});

test.describe('secondaryTests', async () => {
   test.beforeAll(async ({browser}) => {
      page = new CustomPage(await browser.newPage());
   });

   test.beforeEach(async () => {
      await page.goTo("testUrl");
   });

   test.afterEach(async () => {
      await page.close();
   });

   test('example test 2', async () => {
      //Do tests things
      await page.commonFunc(); //Fails here
   });

   test('example test 3', async () => {
      //Do tests things
      await page.commonFunc(); //Passes here
   });
});
```

Example tests 2 and 3 take turns passing and failing.

I would also like to note that all of these tests ran and passed before I turned them into a "test list" file.

Comment: What is the execution order setting in the config?

Comment: @VishalAggarwal I did everything exactly how the [docs](https://playwright.dev/docs/test-parallel#control-test-order) told me to.

Comment: Docs mention all kind of scenarios but that does not clarify what setting you actually end up using in your config file. Please share your config file and definition of commonFunc function.

Comment: @VishalAggarwal I cannot share the definition of `commonFunc`, as it is protected by NDA. As for what I used in my config file, it's literally the last thing on the entire page. The link points a little bit above that.